# Powerbuilder Date Math

Tags: date, report, powerbuilder, date-math

How do I subtract 30 days from a date in PowerBuilder?

I have the following code that returns today's date in a parameter, but I need today - 30 days:

> dw_1.setitem(1, "begin_datetime",
>   datetime(today(), Now()))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you're probably looking for the `RelativeDate` function. Unfortunately, it takes a `Date` and not a `DateTime` as a parameter, but we can get around that:

```
dw_1.setItem(1, "begin_datetime", DateTime( RelativeDate( today(), -30), Now() )
```